Xticks labels are stuck on the top right corner of my plot
My top xticks labels are stuck in the right corner of my matplotlib plot. How to set them in the right place of a time series? The bottom xtick lables are fine. I just want to match the top ones with them. How can I do that? See code and image below.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

time_zones = pd.to_datetime(["2022-07-31 2:00", "2022-07-31 6:00", "2022-07-31 9:00", 
                             "2022-07-31 14:00", "2022-07-31 17:00", "2022-07-31 23:55"])

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(14,8))
ax.spines["top"].set_visible(False)
ax.spines["bottom"].set_visible(False)
ax.spines["right"].set_visible(False)
ax.spines["left"].set_linestyle(":")
ax.spines["left"].set_linewidth(.36) 
ax.plot(df.loc["2022-07-31", "High"], color="green")
ax.plot(df.loc["2022-07-31", "Low"], color="red")

ax.set_ylabel("Price (€)", color="b")
ax.tick_params(labeltop=False, labelbottom=True)
ax.set_xticks(time_zones, ["02:00", "06:00", "09:00", "14:00","17:00", "00:00"])

axT = ax.twiny()
axT.tick_params(labeltop=True, labelbottom=False)
axT.set_xticks(time_zones, ["Hong Kong", "Dubai", "London", "New York","Los Angeles", "Sydney"], fontsize=12, color="b")

ax.grid(True, linestyle=":")
plt.box(False)
plt.show()


I tried to rotate and to set different tick parameters with no success. Can anyone help me here?

Instead of ax.twiny(), ax.secondary_xaxis() can be used.  twiny creates an overlay, unrelated to the original x-axis, and onto which you can plot independently.  secondary_xaxis creates a second x-axis which is linked to the original x-axis (by default, a one-to-one relation, but it could also be used e.g. to plot Celsius at the bottom and Fahrenheit at the top).
If you really want to go with twiny, you need to set the xlim of the top axis equal to the xlim of the bottom axis. By default, the xlim at the top will stay between 0 and 1, which places the timestamp postions far to the right.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range("2022-07-31 0:00", "2022-07-31 23:59", freq='min'))
df['Low'] = 10 + np.random.normal(0.1, 1, len(df)).cumsum()
df['High'] = df['Low'] + 5 + np.abs(np.random.normal(0.02, 1, len(df)).cumsum())

time_zones = pd.to_datetime(["2022-07-31 2:00", "2022-07-31 6:00", "2022-07-31 9:00",
                             "2022-07-31 14:00", "2022-07-31 17:00", "2022-07-31 23:55"])

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(14, 8))
ax.spines["top"].set_visible(False)
ax.spines["bottom"].set_visible(False)
ax.spines["right"].set_visible(False)
ax.spines["left"].set_linestyle(":")
ax.spines["left"].set_linewidth(.36)
ax.plot(df.loc["2022-07-31", "High"], color="green")
ax.plot(df.loc["2022-07-31", "Low"], color="red")

ax.set_ylabel("Price (€)", color="b")
ax.set_xticks(time_zones, ["02:00", "06:00", "09:00", "14:00", "17:00", "00:00"])

axT = ax.secondary_xaxis('top')
axT.set_xticks(time_zones, ["Hong Kong", "Dubai", "London", "New York", "Los Angeles", "Sydney"],
               fontsize=12, color="b")

ax.grid(True, linestyle=":")
plt.box(False)
plt.show()



Thank you for your prompt replay! Both solutions are valiable. It works now!
